# SQL row insert into a table + keys into its linking table within one statement (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: sql, mysql, insert, jdbctemplate

Hey, I'm used to ORM so I have huge absence of sql experience. I want to know what is the best way to insert a row into a table, that is in many-to-many relationship with another table, and within the one statement also insert a row of two foreign keys into the particular linking table to preserve data integrity.

If anybody is using spring jdbcTemplate, I'd also want to know whether it has a support for this task. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's typically what stored procedures are used for, eg something like

```
CREATE PROC MyInsertM2M(@fieldname1 int, @fieldname2 varchar(20), @Key1 int, @Key2 int etc)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO MyMainTable(fieldname1, fieldname2...)
VALUES(@fieldname1, @fieldname2...)

INSERT INTO MyResolverTable(KeyField1, Keyfield2)
VALUES (@Key1, Key2)

END
```

(assuming sql server)

Then google BEGIN TRAN, COMMIT TRAN and ROLLBACK.

Comment: SteveCav, thanks for the reply, but I'd really want to know how it is done without them, I don't like stored procedures much. I'd rather have everything on the application side, leave database out of it

Comment: Your question implies the use of SQL. If you're used to ORM, haven't you used it in a transaction?

Comment: Not speaking of ORM, I usually just created two sql statements in a transaction. I'm a Java programmer, and JDBC driver doesn't allow concatenation of two DB queries. So it results in like 20 lines of code just for inserting a row into a table that is in many2many rel. with another table. That's why I'm wondering whether there is a way of doing this within one SQL statement/query.